# How to treat raw_input variables as integers

Tags: python, raw-input

```
# Mit Print kann ich das Programm den Wert einer Variablen ausgeben/anzeigen lassen

print 'Please choose a number'    
a = raw_input(int)    
print 'Please choose a different number'    
b = raw_input(int)    
print 'Please again choose a different number'    
c = raw_input(int)   
print (a**b)/c
```

Why is this not working? I always get the error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) ** /: 'str' and 'str'

I thought the sign for exponate is **, so why this does not work?

Comment: These questions are well, answerable by just reading the docs. `raw_input` returns a `str` object.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `a`, `b` and `c` are strings rather than integers.

Change

```
a = raw_input(int)
```

to

```
a = int(raw_input())
```

etc.

Answer (score 2):

`raw_input` returns a string as detailed on the [Python docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input).

To do what you are trying you would have to first convert the string to an int like below :

```
a = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this form for each input:

```
a = int(raw_input())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#     print 'Please choose a number'    
a = raw_input('Please choose a number' )    
#     print 'Please choose a different number'    
b = raw_input('Please choose a different number' )    
#     print 'Please again choose a different number'    
c = raw_input('Please again choose a different number')   
print (float(a)**float(b))/float (c)
```

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a **string** not an integer, besides its first argument is the *prompt* that appears before what the user types.

To parse a string into an integer use

```
the_string = raw_input()
the_integer = int(the_string)
```

Alternatively, test whether the string can be parsed into an integer

```
the_integer = None
while the_integer is None:
    print 'Please choose a number'
    the_string = raw_input()
    try:
        the_integer = int(the_string)
    except ValueError:
       print 'That was not a valid number'
```